# Driving Gate from MCU (using 6N136 and TC4431)

Tags: opto-isolator, mosfet-driver, isolation, gate-driving, timing

[image: MCU to GATE]

This is my first time trying to use this optocoupler (6N136)
I'm trying to control a MOSFET gate with the least switching delays (rise and fall timings) possible, while making the MCU isolated from the MOSFET. I can't simulate the TC4431 part, so have to tune things based on datasheets (and trust them)

- Qestion1: about the 6N136 datasheet first page : what does the **"Double Working Voltage - 480V RMS"** mean ?
  [image: 6n136ds]
- Question2: What would be **a valid value for R5**? there seems to be
  no information about it, there's just some recommendations on forums
  about using it to ground the base of transistor inside the
  optocoupler (for faster turn off times?)
- Question3: from the datasheet of TC4431 gate driver IC, it's
  suggested to use a 1k resistor in series with input pin if the input
  voltage is higher than 12 V. that'll be R4 in my schematic? **can I
  decrease it from 10k to 1k?** (since it's a pull-up for the output of
  6N136 as well, doesn't this decreasing make the pull-up too strong?)
  or should I leave it at 10k (or higher maybe?) cause the input pin of
  TC4431 needs no more than 1uA (**is this the value I should consider
  here from the datasheet? "Input Current" @page3**)
- Question4: Are **the two resistors at the final stage** (which
  connect to gate) implemented the right way schematically? (I'll
  adjust the values based on timings. question is about wiring)

Datasheets are here : [6N136](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/6n136-1190309.pdf) , [TC4431](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/21424d.pdf)

Additional info :

- The 12.3V from the buck converter uses the same ground as the MOSFET
  (-BATT)
- PULSE_A is a 3.3V signal from MCU (f=50Hz, T-rise=100nS, T-fall=100nS, **PulseWidth=10uS**)
- Bypass capacitors for the gate driver are not shown. assume they're present.
- The switching characteristics of TC4431 is so promising, and my whole ideal is that the MOSFET is on for the same amount of time as the pulse from MCU (that's 10uS). any delays between signal and MOSFET switching is acceptable, **as long as the MOSFET ON-TIME is 10uS or so**.

Comment: Is 6N136 a requirement? There are far faster (and more reliable -- check the Vcm of 6N136!!) isolators available.

Comment: @TimWilliams I first tried to go with other optocouplers (817, TLP521, phototransistors) but the turn-off tail was too long. So I got fast enough turn on times but slow turn off times. So I searched for high-speed optocouplers, 6N136 and 6N137 and a few other was found, along with many other parts with switching times in ranges of uS. what is Vcm it is just mentioned once in datasheet in a page note. what parts do you suggest?

Comment: Vcm is the voltage applied across the isolation barrier during the dV/dt test; the immunity of 10kV/us is basically useless, or a lie, because the dV is trivially small. Whether this affects your application, I don't know, but it's generally not a good sign for isolated gate drivers where the point is usually to isolate the switching edge itself. 
ISO7710FDR, SI8410BB-D-IS, ADUM110N1BRZ, etc. would be non-optical options here. 6N137, SFH6345 (improved 6N136) and various HCPLxxx would be improved optocoupler options as well.

Comment: Now, do you still want the original question answered? Or has this changed your thoughts a bit, would you like to ask a different question? In any case, as there's no answer yet, you are free to edit your post to whatever question you like.

Comment: @TimWilliams available to me is only 6N136, 6N137, TLP521, TLP350, TP817, Tp814, and many slower parts. So I think I have to go with 6N317. Do you think i can achieve the desired ideal, (that's mosfet being on for 10uS, at 50Hz) by using 6N137 (and adjusting the circuit accordingly) and this specific gate driver? The mosfet is IPB072N15 with Ciss around 5600pF

Comment: @TimWilliams btw what do you mean by _"to isolate the switching edge itself"_ ? I just wanna isolate the MCU to spare it from possible high voltage transients coming from load side.

Comment: If all you need is 10µs (not S, that's siemens) on-time, that could potentially go through a slower one (if a bit marginal). What about range of pulse width? Is this part of a control system or what? || High voltage transients are exactly what I'm talking about, common mode being the voltage between input and output grounds (evidently, `GND` and `-BATT`). You'll have to show a complete schematic before anyone can provide insight into that.

Comment: @TimWilliams It's a circuit I'm trying to design (and actually learn from). The mcu generates low duty cycle pulses, the mosfet must follow the same pulses. But since the load controlled by mosfet is highly inductive and 36v, I thought isolation is required to protect the MCU. I can get away with even 15us or 20us times (i.e mosfet being on for 15us, each time mcu pulses a 10us pw) but the slower I control the mosfet , the more samples I lose. (Program is such that mcu only samples data when mosfet is off)

Comment: @TimWilliams sorry, another question : where do I find the data in the optocouplers datasheets to know about their Vcm? and what is ideal here? asking cause you recommended 6N137 over 6N136, while both are rated the same about "Common Mode Transient Immunity" (not sure if that's the quality to look for)